# Setting value of text field in Java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, textfield

I have a custom field which consists of a drop down list and corresponding text field. I have a map of (display string -> value) e.g. (Dollar -> 50). The keys, here Dollar, are shown in the drop down list and upon its selection, Dollar is shown in the text field.

[image]

Now for the processing purposes, I want to save the corresponding value (50) with the text field.
The js I use for the field is :

```
itemSelectedWithValue: function(itemEle, replaceText,value) {
        var menuEle = itemEle.parentNode;
        var wrapEle = menuEle.parentNode;
        var buttonEle = $(wrapEle).children(".listButton").get(0);
        var fieldId = buttonEle.getAttribute("data-fieldId");
        var fieldEle = document.getElementById(fieldId);
        if(replaceText) fieldEle.value = "";
        // call another function to insert value in fieldElement
        $(fieldEle).trigger("change");
    }
```

Right now nothing is defined in the onChange event. Only onClick is defined :

```
onclick="custField.itemSelectedWithValue(this, true,'Dollar');"
```

The use case is that user can not know the values, like 50. He only sees the display string.

How can we do this? Any suggestions, pointers are welcome.

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: Pointer, don't mix JS and jQuery for DOM manipulation. Use a consistent approach. Second, explain you problem a bit more as it is unclear of what you are asking. If possible, create a JSFiiddle or stack snippet, where we can run and debug your code and simulate the issue

Comment: @Rajesh Thank you for the pointer. The way that the field is defined is not under my control. I literally have very basic understanding of JS, the field value processing is done with java. Also making the field standalone is not possible, as it is a custom field, not the HTML select field.

Answer (score 0):

the option element has a "value" attribute which you can use to store the "50" value

```js
function showVal(){
 var sel = document.getElementById("selCur");
  alert(sel.value);
}
```

```html
<select name='Currency' id='selCur'>
<option value='50'>Dollar</option>
<option value='1'>Rupee</option>
</select>
<input type='button' value='Show Value' onclick='showVal()'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope following script will help you. I've done it using jQuery.

So add jQuery URL to your code.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<form name="f1">
    <input type="text"  id="txt" value=""/>
    <select id="ddlValue">
        <option value="0">--Select--</option>
        <option value="50">Dollar</option>
        <option value="1">Rupee</option>
    </select>      
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ddlValue').change(function () {
            $('#txt').val($('#ddlValue').val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried the standalone script, it replaces the value 50 in the text field. My requirement is user should not see that value, he will only see the Dollar written there. But internally somehow I want to associate 50 with that text field. Like, from Java point of view, may be you are showing name of a variable but changing the value of that variable upon the onChange event?